# What's better to do when we create a new site project?

Tags: theming

I need an advice about beginning a new project layout in Drupal 7. Do you think it is better starting with a basic theme, or creating from zero the project with theme of mine?
I think it is probably better to begin with a basic theme also for the CSS styles that are compatible with all the browsers

What do you say?

Comment: What do you mean with "site project"?

Comment: I mean that i want to create a new site web for a client and i want to know if i must begin for the layout of the site from a basic theme (for example 960gs or basic)

Comment: Here is a question about starting with a base theme in 7. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6682/drupal-theme-bare-minimum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your site and the needs of your client, but it is probably best to start with an easy base theme and then start theming on top of that.

Some good basic base themes are:
[Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) - Best used for responsive HTML5 designs
[Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) - Good basic starter theme
[960gs](http://drupal.org/project/ninesixty) - Good if you need to use a grid format.

Also, you might want to grab some other themes for administration.

Recommended administration themes:
[Rubik](http://drupal.org/project/rubik) - Clean administrative interface
[Admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) - Adds a toolbar at the top of the site, which makes Drupal easier to manage

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i think that i will use 960gs!

Comment: No problem! I personally use [Panels 960gs](http://drupal.org/project/panels_960gs) since I use panels in my designs.

Comment: Panels 960gs i think it's great !I have read the documentation in your link, i will try it!!Thanks

Comment: Zen 5 Responsive Layout is pretty easy to work with (as of late 2012)